# Saving Data On C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, save

How can I save my added buttons when closing the program ? Each time I hit an add button I'm creating a new title which type is button.And each title have it's own specific words.So I must save the words in buttons at the same time.

[image]

Comment: You need to introduce a configuration system to your app. Using that you can save and load such information / settings.

Comment: First you have to find how to save and store data to fit your project's needs, then simply bind to a control that will dynamically generate buttons for you. If you want to store your configuration in for example DB, then when you retrieve a collection of entities from it, you simply bind it to for example a ListView templated to create Buttons as its items.

Comment: Can I save whole button with that or just its strings, word etc ?

Comment: Thanks I'll try both. I already have created database but I must work a lot on it.

Comment: Well, if the only thing that's customizing your button is the string content, then you don't have to save more than that, but if you have for example colors that will personalize your button, or dimensions, you will have to save those also.

Comment: you can persist your data by serializing the Button-Data, e.g. name, color, size into an xml document. This way, the configuration will be available local. If you need it to be shared, you can also use the same technique to store the serialized values inside a database-table (as binaries). This would enable you to choose a config based on a user-login.

Comment: I've another question.What is control template ? Which one is sensible for coding adding button textblock in border or control template ?

Comment: @Thorin Please check out [this link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) as it is really helping us to give you a qualitative answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Find out *what* data needs to be stored. > Define a Model
- Define *how* the Data will be stored > e.g. XML-Serialisation, JSON or whatever
- Define *where* Data will be stored, e.g. Database, File
- Define *when* the Configuration is read and saved

  - eg: read on startup, save on shutdown
- *Handle* your Configuration Data to generate your buttons

Its all up to you. :)

An easy solution might be using `XmlSerializer`, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Another question if I dont add button in xaml design page just add in script page.Will xmlserializer save the codes ?

Comment: I don't really get what you wan't to know, `XmlSerializer` will serialize a *Model* **you define**. If you add a script to the Model of your Buttons, you will be able to save it. The execution though is a whole other thing. Just read the `XmlSerializer`s doc, play around and you will understand.